# Export USER env variable for use in cron

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I have a script that requires the env variable USER to be set. As the script is used by several users, I can't just do `export USER=xxx` at the beginning of the script. I could define in the `crontab`, but I was just wondering whether there is a good way of pulling it in.

I tried sourcing `.bashrc` and `.profile`, but neither define USER, plus on Ubuntu `.bashrc` simply returns on non-interactive shells.

Comment: I'd put the `USER` env definition inside the `crontab` itself. I see nothing wrong in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could work around it by writing at the top of the script (Bashism):

```
USER=$(whoami)
```

or old-style:

```
USER=`whoami`
```

... assuming you have `whoami` in the `PATH`, which can also be set in the `crontab` just like several (most?) other variables. I.e. you can also set the variable in `crontab` itself (at least in Vixies `cron`) - see [here](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html) for example.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`env`](http://man.cx/env) command. Your crontab entry could look like:

```
* * * * * env USER=foouser /path/to/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify environment variable before the command. This way, it won't affect anything else in the crontab.

user.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $USER
```

cli:

```
USER=foo ./user.sh ## outputs "foo"
```